# Display JSON data array from settings_data.json in page template liquid (Shopify)

Tags: arrays, json, shopify, liquid

My setting_data.json (Deput Shopify Theme)file:

```
{
  "current": {
    "checkout_error_color": "#ff6d6d",
    "sections": {
      "header": {
        "type": "header",
        "settings": {
          "align_logo": "left",
          "logo": "shopify:\/\/shop_images\/logo_9bb43dd5-21d6-442c-8a19-0f4adf03e13a.png",
          "logo_max_width": 100,
          "main_linklist": "main-menu",
          "message": true,
          "home_page_only": true,
          "message_text": "Paw Paper – Edible Gift Wrap for Pets",
          "message_link": "",
          "color_bg": "#162950",
          "color_text": "#ffffff"
        }
      },
```

How I can get section header variables in Shopify liquid template page?

I can get one variable:

```
{% assign text_color = settings.color_text %}
{{ text_color }}
```

I need to show custom block on page and get data for it from settings_data.json

```
"1543393771012": {
        "type": "custom-content",
        "blocks": {
          "1543393771012-1": {
            "type": "image",
            "settings": {
              "image": "shopify:\/\/shop_images\/info.png",
              "width": "50%",
              "alignment": "center"
            }
          },
          "1543393802354": {
            "type": "html",
            "settings": {
              "code": "<p>Paw Paper is the world's first edible wrapping paper designed specifically for pets. Our edible paper is 100% all-natural, made from potato starch with Omega-3 enhanced beef flavoring. It's water-soluble so no tape required!<\/p> <p>Just lick it like a stamp or dab water on the edges to bind the seams.<\/p>",
              "width": "50%"
            }
          }
        },
```

But, I can not get and display array with variables.

Help, please.

Comment: where is array in your json?

Comment: How I can get message_text variable from settings_data.json?

Comment: from the first one or second one?

Comment: Let's try from first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings_data.json file isn't something you can access directly in Liquid - but you can access the values stored within using the appropriate Liquid commands.

The global `settings` object in Liquid gives you access to all the variables defined in your `settings_schema.json` file, and nothing more.

However, your `color_text` setting isn't a theme setting, it's a section setting for the section named 'header'.  This variable can be accessed as `section.settings.color_text`, so long as you are calling that from inside your header section.

Block settings are accessed in a similar way.  Assuming that you have some sort of `for block in section.blocks` loop, those block-level settings can be accessed as `block.settings.whatever_key_you_made`

Remember - all of the settings you create have a corresponding scope and need to be accessed appropriately!  `settings_schema.json` gives you your global `settings` object; each section has its private `settings` object; and each block has it's own personal `settings` object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: NB: As a corollary to this scoping, there is no way to access section settings (or, by extension, block settings) inside of asset files.  This is in contrast to the global settings, which _are_ available in assets created with `.liquid` appended to the file name.  CSS styles and Javascript variable declarations that depend on section/block settings must be done inside an inline style/script tag included within the section or block, as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming  your JSONOBJ is correct.

```js
var JSONOBJ={
  "current": {
    "checkout_error_color": "#ff6d6d",
    "sections": {
      "header": {
        "type": "header",
        "settings": {
          "align_logo": "left",
          "logo": "shopify:\/\/shop_images\/logo_9bb43dd5-21d6-442c-8a19-0f4adf03e13a.png",
          "logo_max_width": 100,
          "main_linklist": "main-menu",
          "message": true,
          "home_page_only": true,
          "message_text": "Paw Paper – Edible Gift Wrap for Pets",
          "message_link": "",
          "color_bg": "#162950",
          "color_text": "#ffffff"
        }
      }}}}

console.log(JSONOBJ.current.sections.header.settings.message_text)
```

Comment: I don't want copy all content from settings_data.json to my liquid template. I need to get variables from .json file directly.

Comment: you want it directly means>?

Comment: I need get data directly from .json setting file and display them on the template page.